# Android M keep killing foreground service

Tags: android, service, android-6.0-marshmallow

Why my running service keep being killed on Android Marshmallow while it work normal on 4.x, 5.x
I created extended service + notification and run it as foreground.
However it always being stopped after about 5 minutes (also, notification gone).

```
startForeground(1337, notification);
```

What is the correct method to keep the service running without being killed on android 6.x? Thank you

Comment: I want an answer to this too.

Comment: Looks like a battery optimisation prob